# Normalising my database

Tags: sql, database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I've been working on a scenario for a school behavioural management program. A quick brief of it is: A student carries a daily report card to all of the classes he/she has. A student fills out their section of the report card details which are: Name, Gender, Age, Year Group and then gives the report card to the teacher at the start of each class. The teacher then fills out the teacher details: Title, Name, and Email. The teacher then grades the student out of 10 for the following: Politeness, Participation, Engagement and Improvement. At the end of class the teacher signs the report card and then gives it to the student to sign. The student then the report card home to his/her parents and they sign it too. The final step is the student returning the finished report card to reception to store into the database the next school day.

I have the business rules here:

1. A family can enrol one or more student.
2. A family can contain more than parent or guardian.
3. A student can have only one report card.
4. A class can contain a lot of students.
5. A student can attend many classes.
6. A teacher can teach many students.
7. A student can be taught by many teachers.

I have made an ER Diagram displaying this:

http://i65.tinypic.com/2zfsye0.png

No idea if it's right, oh and the (...) is meaning a compound attribute

Now I have to normalise these tables using a functional dependency diagram but every example I see online only involves one table, I have many! The end goal is to go through 1NF -> 2NF -> 3NF with a brief description on how this works.

I have tried for a week now and I still can't understand it. I know what each NF level requires but I can't seem to figure out how to do it to my table.

Any help or advice is appreciated and I hope this made sense!

Thanks,

Napstur.

Comment: I was never good in going through this theoretically (diagram notation, doing NFs step by step), so I guess I cannot help much. I find it much easier for instance to draw the bridge table from the start than only to draw an n:m line between the tables to be connected. And I always have the IDs in the tables that establish a 1:n relation, rather than only drawing the line. Some questions though: There is a signature in the teachers table. What is this supposed to be? An image of the signature?

Comment: Then: "a student can have only one report card", but this gets filled in every class they attend, so I can imagine the card to look like a book with each page containing a form for a class? You have a table for the card, but wouldn't you also need a table for the page/form? This form would contain the siging persons IDs (for which you'd have to draw lines again to those tables).

Comment: Two minor things: A class should have a subject. A person's age changes every now and then ;-) so you'd rather store the date of birth instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The report card is a daily report card (as in 1 report card per day). The signatures are going to represent a boolean (did they sign, didn't they sign etc.) I agree on the age changing, not so good. Class having a subject, gotcha. Still hoping someone else will see as this doesn't so much help my bigger problem. Although I seriously do appreciate the help you gave me!

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I wish I could help more. So "a student can have only one report card" is wrong. It's a card per student + class (hence many cards per student). As mentioned, when I draw my tables I draw the bridge tables establishing the n:m relations too. So there'd be a table student_class and that would relate to a card, or rather even represent the card!

Comment: Normalization through BCNF is based on functional dependencies. Express your ERD as functional dependencies to start. Make sure you get all of them. For example, `ClassID->RoomNumber, Cstart, CFinish` is obvious, but `RoomNumber, Cstart->ClassID` is probably also true.

Comment: 1. What *reference* are you using for "normalization"? (You don't appear to know what the word means.) 2. Show & justify your normalization work for one table, and where you are stuck explain why. PS 1. A database is in a NF when all its tables are in that NF. 2. Normalization to a particular NF does not go through other NFs, it uses an appropriate algorithm. 3. Some definitions of a NF disallow certain FDs. You can remove one by using the fact that a binary join on a CK of one input is lossless. (But that's not a good way to get good design.)

Comment: You need to know for every table what rows go in it in a given situation, typically in terms of a *predicate*:  a statement template parameterized by columns. The rows making a true statement about a given situation from a table's predicate go in the table. Then business rules about what situations can arise determine what FDs hold. The business rules you have given are cardinalities associated (implicitly) with *particular tables/predicates*. PS What *reference* are you using for ER [sic] modeling/diagraming?